# Simple model viewer for an embedded touch device

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, touchscreen

I'm trying to make an embedded system which will allow people to rotate and generally view a 3D model on a touchscreen. I am using Raspberry Pi 3 for that. The OpenGL part is not a problem as I already have experience with WebGL, but I'm having a **lot** of trouble making some way for the app to be able to display anything on Raspberry.

I installed minimal Raspbian and after a bit of research realised that KMS with direct buffering is the best choice, but... it seems this raspbian doesn't even have DRI (or at least, `/dev/dri`).

How can I make such an app for Raspberry Pi? What options do Pi's hardware and drivers provide?

Comment: I would have thought your best bet would be to run X with a minimal desktop manger then just run any standard openGL code. Rather than trying to run directly in framebuffer.

Comment: @rob "any standard openGL code" still needs a surface and a context, which need to be initiated in some way. Also, a minimal desktop manager isn't needed as if you already have an X client you want to display, you can just startx it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran out of time and ended up using a kiosk-mode Chromium with a canvas as a WebGL context supplier, but here's what I gathered:

1. Raspberry Pi 3 has the option to enable DRM. It's in options presented by running `raspi-config`, under `Advanced Options` -> `Enable experimental GL Driver` or something like that.
2. If you have a program providing a context for you that is also an X client (which currently means any graphical Linux program), such as Chromium in my case, the most efficient way to run it is to use [nodm](https://github.com/spanezz/nodm) to log into a special user, whose .xinitrc does `exec yourprogram`, and [use that .xinitrc to initiate an X session.](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xinit)
3. Chromium has a whole lot of command line switches that enable you to set kiosk mode, without any navigation features, and window geometry/offset, and it's actually pretty light. If you are in the same situation as me, it's actually a pretty good choice.